# Managing csv strings of unique values

Tags: ruby

I have a string of values separated by commas, whose order isn't important, but the uniqueness of the values is. I want to add values to the string, and I end up with something like

```
jruby-1.6.7 :009 > ("1,2,3,1".split(",").to_set << "1" << "4").to_a.join ","
  => "1,2,3,4"
```

which is effective, but looks terrible and goes string -> array -> set -> array -> string, which is no doubt not efficient either.  What's the simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use | (union) operator.
e.g.

```
[ "1", "2", "3" ,"1"] | [ "1", "4"]
```

which shall return,

```
["1","2","3","4"]
```

| (union operator) wont work on strings. so in your case, you can use

```
"1,2,3,4".split(",") | "1,4".split(",")
```

=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

Comment: Hm, ("1,2,3,1".split(",") | ["1","4"]).join "," does look like an improvement..  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'csv'
str = "1,2,3,1"
ar = CSV.parse(str)
ar << ["1","4"]
p ar.flatten.uniq.to_csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[*"1,2,3,1".split(","), "1", "4"].uniq.join ","
```